# Error receiving broadcast Intent Crashes App

Tags: java, android

I have a Service that I start inside an Activity, but everytime the Service tries send the Broadcast back to the Activity I get this error:

> 07-22 17:14:21.890: E/AndroidRuntime(22445):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent {
>   act=com.test.test.countDown flg=0x10 (has extras) } in
>   com.test.test.CookingTimer$1@1de35657 07-22 17:14:21.890:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(22445):  at
>   android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:880)
>   07-22 17:14:21.890: E/AndroidRuntime(22445):  at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)

This is how I call the service:

```
timerIntent = new Intent(CookingTimer.this, TimerService.class);
                startService(timerIntent);
                registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(TimerService.BROADCAST_ACTION));
```

This is my broadcast receiver:

```
private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            updateUI(intent);
        }
    };
```

And finally this is my Service class:

```
public class TimerService  extends Service {

    private Intent intent;
    public static final String BROADCAST_ACTION = "com.test.test.countDown";

    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    private long initial_time;
    long timeInMilliseconds = 0L;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        initial_time = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);  
        handler.removeCallbacks(sendUpdatesToUI);
        handler.postDelayed(sendUpdatesToUI, 1000); // 1 second

    }

    private Runnable sendUpdatesToUI = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            DisplayLoggingInfo();           
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000); // 1 seconds
        }
    };    

    private void DisplayLoggingInfo() {

        timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - initial_time; 

        int timer = (int) timeInMilliseconds / 1000;
        intent.putExtra("time", timer);
        sendBroadcast(intent);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {   
        super.onDestroy();
        handler.removeCallbacks(sendUpdatesToUI);   

    }



    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }


}
```

Can someone explain me why I get that error and how can I possibly fix it? Maybe i'm missing some declaration inside my Manifest?

Comment: If you put a try-catch in the onReceive method, does the exception trace give any extra info? I suspect the problem may be that you're not on the UI thread, but I'm not sure.

Comment: what is the fancy updateUI method you are invoking from inReceive ? Post the complete stacktrace of the exception